# Pulling Information From A String That Is Between Two Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm trying to pull information from a string that is between two characters and append it. I was able to get it to pull the first one between the specified characters but I'm having trouble getting it to output for all of them. Any Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
var $feed = "stuff I don't want: stuff to pull; stuff I don't want: stuff to pull two; stuff I don't want: stuff to pull three;";
var $startMarker = $feed.indexOf(':');
var $endMarker = $feed.indexOf(';',$startMarker);
var $text = $feed.substring($startMarker,$endMarker)
$( "div" ).append("<p>" + $text  +  "</p>");
```

I was also playing around with:

```
var $text2 = $feed.split(':')[3].split(';')[0];
$( "div" ).append("<p>" + $text2  +  "</p>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rtWY7/)**

```
 var feed = "stuff I don't want: stuff to pull; stuff I don't want: stuff to pull two; stuff I don't want: stuff to pull three;";



     var semiSplit=feed.split(";");


        $( "div" ).append("<p>" + semiSplit[0]  +  "</p>");
        $( "div" ).append("<p>" + semiSplit[1]  +  "</p>");
        $( "div" ).append("<p>" + semiSplit[2]  +  "</p>");
```

need only stuff to pull **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rtWY7/2/)**

```
var semiSplitLen=semiSplit.length;
for(var i=0;i<semiSplitLen-1;i++){

    var getStup=semiSplit[i].split(":");
$( "div" ).append("<p>" + getStup[1]  +  "</p>");

}
```

Comment: On your 2nd (need only stuff to pull Working Demo) example I noticed that when I use .replaceWith it only shows the first value. Any thoughts how this could work with .replaceWith?

Comment: @DavidStreck could you reproduce your issue in js fiddle

Comment: Here is a link: [http://dev.creativityflows.com/readrss2.html](http://dev.creativityflows.com/readrss2.html). I'm trying to make it so the data replaces itself instead of adding new paragraphs.

Comment: I'm not able to put it into fiddle because I'm using a php file I wrote. Does the link I provided help?

Comment: @DavidStreck I'm also in.. can you explain the problem a bit more.?

Comment: @DavidStreck If you want to replace your old data, just try to remove the old one before appending the new one.. like `$('div').empty()` and then proceed appending the new ones...

Comment: @Manishankar I wrapped the code in a setInterval() so when the string updates it will add/update the values being appended every second. Instead of making the page longer with the new values I'm trying to replace the first output of it. There are 13 paragraphs in the first output. instead of outputting 13 each time it will just replace the first 13. Make sense?

Comment: use `$( "div p:lt(14)" ).remove();` to remove the first 13 paragraphs from it.. can you use this..?

Comment: @Manishankar Thanks! That did the trick. Not sure how I forgot about .empty XD

Comment: @DavidStreck ok i think the other guy's comment helped you in this.. Atleast for a good manners, just let him know that his code has did the trick for you... :)